# Python time-parsing fails, when TZ is in the environment

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

The following simple script:

```py
from datetime import datetime as DT

ts  = 'Mon Aug 17 12:49:28 EDT 2020'
fmt = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
dts = DT.strptime(ts, fmt)
print(dts)
```

works normally, when I simply invoke Python with it:

```
% python3.7 t.py
2020-08-17 12:49:28
```

However, if I add a *different* timezone to the environment, the script fails:

```
% env TZ=UTC python3.7 t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 5, in <module>
    dts = DT.strptime(ts, fmt)
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/opt/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Mon Aug 17 12:49:28 EDT 2020' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'
```

I tried with earlier Python-versions -- 2.7 and 3.6 -- and got the same error. Even setting the `TZ` to `EDT` does not work, although the value of `America/New_York` (which is my computer's `/etc/localtime`) seems Ok.

How can such timestamps be parsed reliably?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `dateutil`'s parser.parse with a time zone mapping dict:

```
import dateutil
ts = 'Mon Aug 17 12:49:28 EDT 2020'

# add more time zone names / abbreviations as key-value pairs here:
tzmapping = {'EDT': dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern')}

dt = dateutil.parser.parse(ts, tzinfos=tzmapping)

print(dt)
print(repr(dt))
# 2020-08-17 12:49:28-04:00
# datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 17, 12, 49, 28, tzinfo=tzfile('US/Eastern'))
```

Time zone name abbreviations are inherently ambiguous and won't be parsed by `%Z`. Exceptions are UTC and GMT - however, also be careful with that! %Z *accepts* e.g. a literal "UTC" but it doesn't result in an aware datetime object. Again, dateutil's parser does a better job than the standard lib's datetime.strptime.