# Unable to read time with timezone provided in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, datetime-format

I am trying to read time from a string which looks like

`08/18/2020 08:42:00.000 EDT`

I tried reading the string using

`datetime.strptime(tempTime,'%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f %Z')`

The EDT part is creating a problem. It says wrong format. If I remove the EDT and %Z, it works fine.

I know it can be done but that's a rather tedious way(Converting from one format to another).
Can this be done simply?

Comment: here's a way to do it using `dateutil` and a time zone mapping dict: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63463267/10197418 You'll need the tz mapping since `EDT` might only be parsed on some machines (that happen to run in US/Eastern time zone).

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks. This is what I was looking for.